# How change widget of a "between exposed filter" to combo box?

Tags: views

I have a view that has some exposed filters. One of the filters is on the price of the content type. I want to filter contents by price when price is between two known value. For example I want to filter all the content that their prices are between 0 and 5000. The other thing I want is a select box for this filter. So the filter is a select box with some options like below:

```
<option>0-5000</option>
<option>5000-10000</option>
<option>10000-15000</option>
<option>15000-20000</option>
```

I add a filter to the view and mark it as exposed filter, then change its operator to between. Now what should I do to change the widget from two text box to a single select box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. After you expose the filter, change it from Single filter to Grouped filters using the radios right below the expose checkbox. Then you can define what each option is and make it a select box.

[image]